# How can I create a Rg.Plugins.PopUp page in C#? Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, popup

Here is my attempt:

```
    public class DomainPopUp : PopupPage
    {
        StackLayout _frameLayout;
        
        public DomainPopUp()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("D9FFFFFF");

            _frameLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

            Frame blueFrame = new Frame
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

            _frameLayout.Children.Add(blueFrame);

            StackLayout blueLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Spacing = 0 
            };

            blueFrame.Content = blueLayout;

            Label domainArea = new Label
            {
                Text = "Domain",
                FontSize = 30,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            };

            blueLayout.Children.Add(domainArea);
        }
    }
```

When I click on the button opening this PopUpPage, only the white background appears (which I designated with `BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("D9FFFFFF");`).

I assume I have to do something similar to "Content = _frameLayout" in order to get the stack layout with the blue frame to appear. What is this code for pop ups? How can I get it to appear?

Comment: Set the `Content` property to `blueFrame`

Comment: Thank you; that worked!

Comment: Can you share your comment to answer and accept it? It will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: mshwf give you a solution to fix this issue, you can post his solution to blew "Your Answer"  and accpet yourself answer(click the ✔ in upper left corner of your answer) after two days.